# How to efficiently save ongoing results while using df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, output

Gurus,

I am trying to use a function Process_Data() to process data from a dataframe 'df' as follows:

```
  def Process_Data(row):
  ...
  return(row)    

  def main():
  ...    
  df= df.apply(Process_Data, axis=1)
```

I would like to save some intermediate results to a file while processing each row in the dataframe 'df', what would be the best practice?  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
   Process_Row(row)
```

or

```
for row in df.itertuples():
   Process_Row(row)
```

iterrows returns a row as a series object, itertuple returns the row as a tuple.

itertuples will be more efficient but it may depend on what type of object you want to manipulate.